# Can We Move the Position of a Reduced Relative Clause?

Tags: participle-clauses, restrictive-clauses, supplementation

> The train **now arriving at Platform 3** is the 4.20 to Paddington.

Can I move the position of reduced relative clause like this?

> **Now arriving at Platform 3**, the train is the 4.20 to Paddington.
>
> The train is the 4.20 to Paddington, **now arriving at Platform 3**.

And can we omit a comma like this?

> Now arriving at Platform 3 the train is the 4.20 to Paddington.
>
> The train is the 4.20 to Paddington now arriving at Platform 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the moves, and in one case you can omit the comma, but they mean somewhat different things.

> The train now arriving at Platform 3 is the 4.20 to Paddington. *The sentence names the specific train now arriving.*
>
> Now arriving at Platform 3, the train is the 4.20 to Paddington. *The sentence names a previously mentioned train and adds the information that it is now arriving. Omitting the comma would not change the sense, but it would violate both formal and substantive typographic convention: the clause must by position be non-restrictive and it must be spoken with ‘comma intonation’, a falling tone on ‘3’.*
>
> The train is the 4.20 to Paddington now arriving at Platform 3. *Omitting the comma makes this a restrictive clause, implying that you are speaking of just one of two or more 4.20s to Paddington, which is unlikely.*